# Unapplied Django Database Migrations Error: Ensuring Database Schema Consistency

Tags: python, django, database, rdbms

`class PatientHistory(models.Model):
HIV_STATUS = [
('Not Applicable','Not Applicable'),
('Positive','Positive'),
('Negative','Negative')

```
]

DELIVERY_STATUS = [
    ('Not Applicable','Not Applicable'),
    ('Primary','Primary'),
    ('Secondary','Secondary'),
]
patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="patient_history", blank=False)
date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
age = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
blood_pressure = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
allergy = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
previous_surgery = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
incident_history = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
previous_hospital_treatment = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
previous_document_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='reports/', blank=True, null=True)
hiv = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=HIV_STATUS, default="Not Applicable", blank=False, null=False)
family_history = models.TextField()
delivery = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DELIVERY_STATUS, default="Not Applicable", blank=False, null=False)
note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)

def __str__(self):
    return f"history {self.pk}"`
```

I have encountered an issue with my Django application. I made changes to the PatientHistory model by adding a new field and then ran the makemigrations and migrate commands. However, when I executed the migrate command, an error occurred:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'patienthistory_patienthistory' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: patienthistory_patienthistory.family_history_id contains a value 'asdasd' that does not have a corresponding value in patienthistory_familyhistory.id.`

To resolve this issue, I know that I can delete the development database (SQLite in my case) and re-run the makemigrations and migrate commands to recreate the database with the new changes. However, I would like to find a solution that does not involve deleting the development database. This way, I can avoid potential problems in the future where I might have to delete the production database.

I am seeking a solution that can fix this problem without deleting the development database. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my new table.

````
    HIV_STATUS = [
        ('Not Applicable','Not Applicable'),
        ('Positive','Positive'),
        ('Negative','Negative')
        
    ]

    DELIVERY_STATUS = [
        ('Not Applicable','Not Applicable'),
        ('Primary','Primary'),
        ('Secondary','Secondary'),
    ]
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="patient_history", blank=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    age = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    blood_pressure = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    allergy = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    previous_surgery = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    incident_history = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    previous_hospital_treatment = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    previous_document_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='reports/', blank=True, null=True)
    hiv = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=HIV_STATUS, default="Not Applicable", blank=False, null=False)
    delivery = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DELIVERY_STATUS, default="Not Applicable", blank=False, null=False)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"history {self.pk}"

class FamilyHistory(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(PatientHistory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="patient_family", blank=False, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=False)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=False)
    relation_with_patient = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)```
````

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.